# keyword.url setting in firefox getting overriden by Anti-virus Settings

Tags: firefox, default-settings

I am trying to set the value for `keyword.url` in the `about:config` page of mozilla firefox as `https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=`.

But it is getting overidden quickly by the anti-virus that is installed on the machine to 
`http://isearch.avg.com/search?....`.

Can anyone help me out here, to setup the default search engine in firefox to google ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the AVG Firefox add-on. The default search engine would no more get over-written.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall AVG, or disable AVG's SafeSearch feature

Comment: I was looking for options in AVG settings. The problem was, it has installed a addon in firefox, disabling which resolved the issue. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: @mtk If you found a solution, you can provide a new answer yourself. This will be helpful to other users with the same issue. :)